# How to change the confirmed_flush_lsn to a smaller value

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication, debezium

#### Problems

Currently, when creating a replication slot using `CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT`, the values of
`catalog_xmin`, `restart_lsn`, and `confirmed_flush_lsn` are set to **the latest xid and lsn**.

However, during the subsequent consumption of WAL log data, the server is instructed to start streaming WAL for logical replication, starting at either WAL location XXX/XXX or the slot's confirmed_flush_lsn (see Section 54.19), whichever is greater. **This means that it is not possible to consume data from before the confirmed_flush_lsn.**

If I want to start consuming from an earlier position in the streaming process, how to change the confirmed_flush_lsn to a smaller value?（ Obviously, `pg_slot_advance` can’t do that)

How to change the confirmed_flush_lsn to a smaller value? or how to initialize an specified earlier confirmed_flush_lsn slot?

#### Situations

For example, in Flink CDC or《DBLog: A Generic Change-Data-Capture Framework》, read snapshot in multiple chunks in parallel. For each chunks:

1. read current Lsn as low_watermark.
2. read snapshot chunk.
3. read current Lsn as high_watermark.
4. backfill logs between [low_watermark, high_watermark).

To decease slot numbers pressure, I want to read low_watermark and high_watermark without slot creation. Create this slot later when need. (Meantime, a global slot is retained to avoid log to be recycled.

However, a slot create later cannot read Wal-Log before created.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Like Flink CDC or《DBLog: A Generic Change-Data-Capture Framework》, read snapshot in chunks and then backfill logs between [low_watermark, high_watermark) for each snapshot chunk. To decease slot numbers pressure,  I want to read [low_watermark, high_watermark) first without creating a new slot. Create this slot later when need.(Meantime, a global slot is retained to avoid log to be recycled.  @Laurenz Albe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by using built-in commands or utilities, you cannot change the confirmed_flush_lsn in PostgreSQL to a smaller value or initialize it to an earlier position once a replication slot has been created.The confirmed_flush_lsn represents the point up to which the data has been safely replicated, and it's not intended to be moved backward.

Usually, you would need to establish a new replication slot and begin replication from the desired point if you want to consume data from an earlier position in the WAL stream.

Comment: How to begin replication from the desired point?